# binding.getRoot() - Can not resolve method

Tags: android, android-viewbinding

On Android Studio 3.6.3 (latest in the stable channel). I'm using `ViewBinding` and it is working normally but in every activity, this error has started popping up. It doesn't affect anything, the project builds normally and the app runs fine but the error is there in every file with ViewBinding.

Why is that so? It started happening recently.

What I've tried:

- Delete the .idea folder and .iml files
- Invalidate caches/restart
- Clean/rebuild project

Answer (score 0):

Deleting the **caches** folder in `C:\Users\*username*\.AndroidStudio3.6\system` seems to have fixed the issue.